# Creating a form that feeds data into 2 models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it just me or are the rails form helpers incapable of accommodating more than one model. I have two tables which collectively describe generic "devices." I have brand, model, and submodel in one DB table, and style and avatar (through paperclip) stored in another. For a particular brand+model+submodel there may be many styles available, so I decided to separate out the styles into a different table. When entering new "devices" I would like to be able to select the style of the device and upload an image as well.

However, this seems impossible with rails without creating a second page for entering styles, once the brand+model+submodel form has been submitted. I would also like the foreign key for brand+model+submodel to be attached to my style. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Create your own controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two tables have an ActiveRecord association (like has_one, has_many, etc) then take a look at nested object forms. The following link might help - http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes